# Redirect to subdomain after successful login in angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, angular, subdomain, angular2-routing, redirect

I am developing a angular2 app. I need to redirect to the user from **www.example.com** to **admin.example.com** after a successful login. How can I acheive this in angular 2? Also how can I test it on my localhost ?

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 2):

You dont need angular to do what you need -

Simply do something like

```
window.location.href = "http://admin.example.com";
```

When you received the successfull login response.

Have a look here for further info: 
[How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery)

I could have presented this in a jsfiddle for you, but seems like the service is broken (atleast for me) atm - as it wont give me a sharing URL.

Comment: Sumit, please mark this as the correct answer if this solved your need :)